# Как хранить блокчейн?

Tags: python, blockchain

Пишу тестовый проект по созданию блокчейна. Из-за отсутствия других узлов в сети появилась потребность сохранять созданную цепочку в отдельный файл или БД, чтобы при запуске программы восстанавливать его оттуда, а не каждый раз создавать новый.
Каким более оптимальным способом это можно реализовать?

Comment: Выбор оптимального хранилища зависит от многих параметров. Сколько данных, как часто они будут обновляться/добавляться/удаляться, по каким ключам будет вестись их поиск (если будет поиск), каковы по природе данные - бинарные или они могут быть представлены в текстовом виде...

Comment: я бы посмотрел на то, как сохраняются блоки в гите - каждый блок - отдельный файл. имя файла - хеш этого блока. Так как файлов может быть много, то лучше по первым двух (а может Вам и одного хватит) сделать каталоги. И все. Внутри я бы хранил в виде json или даже просто текст (если это совсем тестовый проект), главное где то в начале добавить признак версии файла (к примеру, это может быть первая строка или первые 5-10 символов файла) и можно будет легко перейти от json к toml или бинарным данным, и даже смешивать.

Answer (score 0):

Использовал модуль "pickle":

Записал методы в класс блокчейна:

```
def __getstate__(self) -> dict:
    state = {}
    state['chain'] = self.chain
    state['current_transactions'] = self.current_transactions
    state['difficulty'] = self.difficulty
    state['blockTime'] = self.blockTime
    return state

def __setstate__(self, state: dict):
    self.chain = state['chain']
    self.current_transactions = state['current_transactions']
    self.difficulty = state['difficulty']
    self.blockTime = state['blockTime']
```

В тот же класс добавил метод сохранения в файл:

```
def save(self):
    with open("chain.pkl", "wb") as fp:
        pickle.dump(self, fp)
```

Восстанавливаю из файла так:

```
with open("chain.pkl", "rb") as fp:
    blockchain = load(fp)
```